# Docker Container install on windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm a complete noob when it comes to docker so I might be having a very silly problem but I cant seem to fix it.

I'm trying to install a container on Windows. This one:

```
docker run --pull=always
           --volume /your/download/path/:/data/downloads \
           --volume /your/storage/path/:/data/db \
           --log-driver json-file \
           --log-opt max-size=10m \
           -p 6500:6500 \
           --name rdtclient \
           rogerfar/rdtclient:latest
```

After replacing some lines with my storage location and such, all I get is;

```
"Missing expression after unary operator '--'"
"Unexpected token 'volume' in expression or statement"
```

On almost every line. Like I said I'm new to this so if anyone here knows what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Are you running this command in a single line or multiple lines, as they show in their README on github (https://github.com/rogerfar/rdt-client#docker-run)? If you are using multiple lines, you need that \ character at the end of each line, otherwise Docker does not recognize the second --volume and so it throws an error.

Comment: I tried running as a single line and I got this: "docker: invalid reference format."

Comment: Be careful of the / in Windows, instead of \ (if you copy paste your local path from Explorer). Just tried this in my Windows 10 laptop and it works 

docker run --pull=always --volume C:/my/path:/data/downloads --volume C:/my/path:/data/db --log-driver json-file --log-opt max-size=10m -p 6500:6500 --name rdtclient rogerfar/rdtclient:latest

Comment: Until you become more familiar with running shell commands, I suggest simplifying. Things such as logging, name, etc are not required to get the container running. Try understand what each option does and build up.